# Crane Balancing, Center of mass

Tags: algorithms

I am working on the ICPC 2014 [Problem C "Crane Balancing"](http://icpc.baylor.edu/worldfinals/problems/icpc2014.pdf)

The initial idea was to calculate the center of mass of the polygon, which I did via this equation:
[image]

[image]

Where the Area A:

[image]

Now, the solution is to binary search over the mass and look for th e maximum mass M where the crane is still balanced.

But I have a problem figuring out how the mass added affects the position of the polygon center of mass,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that your crane is lying on the side set `L` on the axis `c`, where `L` can be just a point, can be just a line section `[Ai, Bi]`, or can be unity of points and line sections.
You don't need to know how the mass affects the crane, you just need to now the **minimal** and **maximal** mass, for which the `x` coordinate of the center of mass is between `infinum(L)` and `supremum(L)`.
Now, just brute force for all the vertices, and for each of them find the mass that it can handle.

And, the x coordinate of the centroid of the new system **crane - lifted object**, where the object is attached to the vertice `(xi, yi)`, can be calculated by the following formula (knowing the mass of both objects):

`Cx_new = Cx + (xi - Cx) * Mo/(Mc + Mo)`

Where `Cx` is the x coordinate of the centroid of the crane,  `Mo` is the mass of the object, `Mc` is the mass of the crane (can be calculated as `Area * 1 kg/m^2`).

And knowing the `infinum(L)` and `supremum(L)`, you can easily find the mass that your crane can handle.

So, finding the `Cx` and `Cy` can be done in `O(n)`, finding the `MinMass` and `MaxMass` for fixed vertice `(xi, yi)` can be done in `O(1)`, and looping through all these vertices can be done in `O(n)`, the final complexity is `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to find mass center of the whole system **polygon** - **added mass** and ensure that this center is located above polygon bottom base (without going over the extreme points)

```
CommonCenter.X=(PolyCenter.X*Poly.Mass + AddedMass.X*AddedMass.Mass)/(Poly.Mass+AddedMass.Mass)
CommonCenter.Y=(PolyCenter.Y*Poly.Mass + AddedMass.Y*AddedMass.Mass)/(Poly.Mass+AddedMass.Mass)
```

(look at *A system of particles* and *Barycentric coordinates* parts [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass#A_system_of_particles))

Comment: Yeah i understand this, but how do we calculate the mass center of the polygon + addedMass (at point x,y) ?

Comment: @yahya el fakir  Formula added